# Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement Fails Build

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We have a cross platform mobile application solution built on top of Xamarin targeting Android and UWP.  On every solution build there is roughly a 50/50 chance of receiving the following error:

> Error : Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't
>   exist in the Mono for Android profile? at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters) at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies.<>c__DisplayClass37_0.b__1()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke() at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

When receiving the error, if I turn around and immediately build the solution again the issue generally goes away.  To further complicate the matter any of the Android projects in the solution can report this error, meaning it's not a single project giving me the problem.  While annoying on my local machine, this introduces a lot of clutter when our CI-builds are constantly failing only to work when re-queuing the build.

I have attempted to remove and re-add the Xamarin nuget packages to the project.  I've even deleted all the project files and created brand new ones, to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Upload a [.binlog](http://msbuildlog.com/) when this fails so one can capture more context to this failure.

Comment: Thanks @JonDouglas I'll give that a shot.  Having trouble getting the build to fail now...

Comment: @JonDouglas here is a link to the binlog with the error https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhshToG50nqhhe8DaJo1VN-rJZkAqQ